# Добавление в новый столбец файла Excel данных из других столбцов

Tags: python, pandas

Имеем файл excel. Как добавить новый столбец, потом в этот столбец добавить данные из трех столбцов через запятую, в конце записать все данные в excel

```
import pandas as pd
    
#  Чтение файла 'city_all_geo.xlsx' - лист 'Лист1' - название и значение всех столбцов.
city_all_geo = pd.read_excel('city_all_geo.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1', usecols=['Населенный пункт', 'Улица', 'Номер дома', 'Тип строения', 'Этажность', 'Почтовый индекс', 'Широта', 'Долгота', 'Наименование строения'])
    
#  Создаем новый столбик 'Полный адрес' и записываем в него через запятую 'Населенный пункт', 'Улица', 'Номер дома'. Сортируем по алфавиту.
city_all_geo["Полный адрес Широта и Долгота"] = city_all_geo['Населенный пункт']\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Улица'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Номер дома'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Широта'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Долгота'].astype(str), sep=", ")
    
data = city_all_geo["Полный адрес Широта и Долгота"].sort_values()
     
city_all_geo.to_excel("city_all_geo_full_streets's.xlsx")

# или

data.to_excel("city_all_geo_full_streets's.xlsx")
```

У меня записывается либо первоначальный файл, либо изменения.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("/mnt/c/users/us/downloads/Без имени 1.xlsx")
df["Lat, Lon, Address"] = df.apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

df.head()
```

```
    Lat       Lon   Address  Lat, Lon, Address
0   54.1342 34.16743    a   54.1342,34.16743,a
1   54.1523 34.17684    b   54.1523,34.17684,b
2   54.1704 34.18625    c   54.1704,34.18625,c
3   54.1885 34.19566    d   54.1885,34.19566,d
4   54.2066 34.20507    e   54.2066,34.20507,e
```

```py
df.to_excel("/mnt/c/users/us/downloads/Без имени 1.xlsx", columns=df.columns, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ответ был прост:

import pandas as pd
    
#  Чтение файла 'city_all_geo.xlsx' - лист 'Лист1' - название и значение всех столбцов.
city_all_geo = pd.read_excel('city_all_geo.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1', usecols=['Населенный пункт', 'Улица', 'Номер дома', 'Тип строения', 'Этажность', 'Почтовый индекс', 'Широта', 'Долгота', 'Наименование строения'])
    
#  Создаем новый столбик 'Полный адрес' и записываем в него через запятую 'Населенный пункт', 'Улица', 'Номер дома'. Сортируем по алфавиту.
city_all_geo["Полный адрес Широта и Долгота"] = city_all_geo['Населенный пункт']\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Улица'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Номер дома'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Широта'].astype(str), sep=", ")\
    .str.cat(city_all_geo['Долгота'].astype(str), sep=", ")
    
city_all_geo.sort_values(['Полный адрес Широта и Долгота'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
     
city_all_geo.to_excel("city_all_geo_full_streets's.xlsx")
```